# Docker networking forwarding failed

Tags: docker, networking, dns, apache2, local

I got a problem regarding Docker networking. I've a php (non-framework) and mysql setup with Docker Compose and Docker Desktop. Mysql is using port 3636 and is working perfectly, like: I can reach him on both inside a Docker Container and on my local. But once I open the web application with php, I can do a curl inside the Docker Container and got a 302 message and can see the application by command line, but once I try it on my local environment (my computer), I got the following error:

- `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

It doesn't seems to make sense, my web application is running on 36001, I debug it and got the following information:

My computer:

- localhost [127.0.0.1] 36001 open
- com.docke 23209 ***   97u  IPv6 0x5***d5b      0t0  TCP *:36001 (LISTEN)

Docker Container:

- User
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
- Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 36001 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
- {"36001/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"36001"}],"80/tcp":null}

Docker stack trace (log):

```
2024-03-27 19:25:34 [Wed Mar 27 18:25:34 2024] PHP 8.3.4 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:36001) started
2024-03-27 19:26:04 [Wed Mar 27 18:26:04 2024] 127.0.0.1:54472 Accepted
2024-03-27 19:26:04 [Wed Mar 27 18:26:04 2024] 127.0.0.1:54472 [302]: GET /
2024-03-27 19:26:04 [Wed Mar 27 18:26:04 2024] 127.0.0.1:54472 Closing
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME?error}
    env_file:
      - path: .env
        required: true
    environment:
      LANGUAGE: ${LANGUAGE?error}
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        LANGUAGE: ${LANGUAGE?error}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "${WEB_PORT?error}:${WEB_PORT?error}"
    volumes:
      - .:${CONTAINER_WORKDIR?error}
    depends_on: # only if you're using the database service
        - database
    networks:
      - testnetwork
    init: true

  # Conditionally include database service if DATABASE_ENGINE is not 'none'
  database:
    env_file:
      - path: .env
        required: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_NAME}'
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT?error}
      DB_SQL_PATH: ${DB_SQL_PATH?error}
    image: ${DATABASE_ENGINE}:${DB_VERSION}
    command: mysqld --sql_mode=""
    hostname: mysql
    ports:
        - '${DATABASE_PORT?error}:${DATABASE_PORT?error}'
    volumes:
        - 'test-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './${DB_SQL_PATH?error}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/${DB_SQL_PATH?error}'
    networks:
        - testnetwork
    healthcheck:
        test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p test" ]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s

networks:
    testnetwork:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    test-mysql:
        driver: local
```

The Docker Compose is modified on arguments and environment because otherwise it would be a long code display inside the question.

Comment: Thanks mate! Its fixed. Can you place it as a answer, so I can mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application binds to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). That means it'll only accept connections from there. In a container, it'll only accept connections from inside the container.

You need to bind to 0.0.0.0 for it to accept connections from outside the container.

The key log message to look for is `Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:36001) started`. That needs to change to 0.0.0.0.